# Convert GPS Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees

Tags: vb.net, gps, coordinates, degrees

I have a formula that I am using to calculate decimal degrees from gps coordinates.

GPS Coordinates:
3800.5825,N
08735.5417,W

Formula:

```
Private Function DMStoDD(ByVal toConvert As Double, ByVal Dir As String) As Double
    Dim DD As Double
    Dim deg As Double
    Dim min As Double
    Dim sec As Double
    deg = CDbl(toConvert.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
    min = CDbl(toConvert.ToString.Substring(2, 2))
    sec = CDbl(toConvert.ToString.Split(".")(1)) * 0.01
    DD = deg + (min / 60) + (sec / 3600)
    'Negative for West
    If Dir = "W" Then DD = DD * -1
    Return DD
End Function
```

Returns:
38.0161805555556
-87.5983805555556 (negative for west)
The results are very close, but not quite right.  I believe that they are just a little bit North West of where they actually should fall.  I have searched and looked at a lot of different formulas, but from what I've read, I think that mine should be right.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: See [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000361000000).

Comment: There's no formula there, that's using the esri sdk and creating a DDCoordinate from a DMS String.  I believe there should be a way to convert this rather than including an additional sdk.

Comment: Under "Example" is additional information which appears to correspond with my code above: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

Comment: Turns out based on the calculator [here](http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html) my results may in fact be correct.  Maybe it's a GPS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula looks wrong, the part with the seconds! it tries a DMS to Degrees conversion. But you coordinates are in DM notation ( Degrees + Decimal minutes)

so you need a DM to DEG conversion. 
 08735.5417,W = 87deg 35.5147 minutes W

just do 87 + 35.5147/60, then multiply with -1

Comment: Thanks! After a few days of looking at the issue I came to the same conclusion. This did resolve my issue