# How To Convert DMS To DD (Co-Ordinates) With VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, coordinates, geography

I am struggling very much at the moment to convert DMS to DD within VB.NET & after searching endlessly & having no luck I've opened this Q in hopes that another user has come across this issue & resolved it hopefully in the past!

I am trying to convert a DMS of N51°4.212', E0°12.905' to DD.

After reading this Q & the answer:
[Convert GPS Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752150/convert-gps-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-degrees)

I had this function which threw out completely incorrect DD co-ordinates (50.9298, -0.215083333333333):

```
Private Function DMS_To_DD(ByVal Degrees As String, ByVal Mins As String, ByVal Secs As String) As String
        Dim TmpMins As String = CStr(Mins) & "." & Secs
        Return CInt(Degrees) + (CDbl(TmpMins) / 60) * -1
    End Function
```

& then read this page: http://simoncodersoftware.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/convert-dms-to-dd-using-vb-net/

That lead me to this function:

```
Private Function DMS_To_DD(ByVal Degrees As String, ByVal Mins As String, ByVal Secs As String) As String
        Dim TotalSecs As Integer = CInt(Mins) * 60 + Secs
        Dim Total_2 As Double = TotalSecs / 3600
        Dim X1 As String = CStr(CInt(Degrees) & CStr(Total_2))
        If X1.StartsWith("-") Then
            Return X1.Substring(0, 3) & X1.Substring(4, 5)
        Else
            Return X1.Substring(0, 2) & X1.Substring(3, 5)
        End If
    End Function
```

Which returned invalid co-ordinates: 51.1255, 0045138

Both functions being called with:
DMS_To_DD(51, 4, 212)
DMS_To_DD(0, 12, 905)

Any ideas where I am going wrong here? This issue is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function is using a totally wrong formula. Whereas the second one, the function is expecting an integer minutes, or in other words, converts the decimal minutes to integer.

> **Both functions being called with: DMS_To_DD(51, 4, 212) DMS_To_DD(0, 12, 905)**

Also your understanding of coordinates value representation is wrong. N51°4.212' is not equal to 51 degrees, 4 minutes and 212 seconds. Same goes with E0°12.905' <> 0 degrees, 12 minutes and 905 seconds.

**UPDATES**

Sorry, the previous function only work for +ve degrees. I have changed the formula to take care of NSWE of DMS value properly at the cost of an extra parameter `nswe` to the function to determine sign of the returned decimal degrees. Try this:

```
Private Function DMS_To_DD(nswe As String, ByVal deg As UInteger, ByVal min As Double, ByVal sec As Double) As Double
    ' throw exception if min and/or sec are negative values
    If min < 0 Or sec < 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("min and/or sec", "Argument must be a positive value.")
    End If

    Dim sign As Integer

    ' nswe checking below only considers 's' or 'w' value 
    ' in order to determine -ve degrees. 
    ' 'n', 'e' or any invalid string will be default to +ve degrees.
    Select Case nswe.ToUpper
        Case "S", "W" : sign = -1
        Case Else : sign = 1
    End Select

    Return sign * (deg + (min * 60 + sec) / 3600)
End Function
```

E.g:

To convert N54° 6.279':

```
DMS_To_DD("N", 54, 6.279, 0) ' returns 54.10465
```

To convert W4° 44.362':

```
DMS_To_DD("W", 4, 44.362, 0) ' returns -4.73936666666667
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great but then it failed on something like this: N54°6.581', W4°43.638' - Which lead me into the sea! Any ideas why this happened?

Comment: Also, just seen your amendment, if these are not Degrees, Mins, Seconds (E0°12.905'). How could I convert this specific format to DD?

Comment: Incase I didn't make sense, I mean, E.g. How did you get 51, 4, 12.72 from 51, 4.212

Comment: West longitude and south latitude is -ve degrees. So you have to pass -ve degrees. Eg: For W4°43.638' --> `DMS_To_DD(-4, 43.638, 0)`.

Comment: N51°4.212' means degree=51 and minutes=4.212. 0.212 of a minute is equal to 12.72 seconds. So 4.212 minutes is equal to 4 minutes and 12.72 seconds. Simpler example is like 5.5 minutes. The decimal part (0.5) is half of a minute, therefore to represent it as minute and second, it's equal to 5 minutes and 30 seconds. 1 min = 60 secs. 0.5 min=30 secs. 0.25 min=15 secs.

Comment: Thanks, this put me in-land but still not the correct co-ordinates, E.g. N54 6.279, W4 44.362 Returns: 54.10465, -3.26063333333333 - One of which is England & the other the Isle of Man.

Comment: I have updated the function to fix -ve degrees. And a point on the map is identified with latitude and longitude. N54 6.279 and W4 44.362 is located on Isle of Man.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this issue was that even with the - symbol added N54 6.279, W4 44.362 which is in the Isle of man converts to 54.10465, -3.26063333333333 which is not in the Isle of man which is where I was stuck!